# SQL Reporting Services Integrate to SharePoint

Tags: reporting-services, sharepoint-2007

I have prepared 3 reports in SQL Server Reporting Services 2008r2 and I want to integrate them into the SharePoint2007. But, I have no idea how to do. I am very new about SharePoint. I have searched too many sources but I didn't get information properly. Is SharePoint only way to broadcast the reports in the company or is there any other ways to share the reports in the company? Could you show me a way to follow?

Comment: You distribute the reports via a report manager which is `http://yourReportServerName/reports`

Comment: @JonH How can the other employees reach to these reports?

Comment: Its a public intranet, running on IIS.  Basically its a website, so they just navigate to it.

Comment: @JonH I have deployed two reports into the my local report server in my comp. How can I delete these deployed reports?

Comment: Go to the report manager where it lists all the reports.  Click detailed view, select the 2 reports and click delete.  I think you need a book on RS.

Comment: Check: [Features Supported by Reporting Services in SharePoint Integrated Mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/bb326290(v=sql.105).aspx)